# Calculating time between different rows

Tags: r

I am having issues coming up with a solution to calculate the difference in time between two dates that are not in the same row. For instance I have the following data:

```
dates_edited          end_fast_c        start_fast_c
1         4/1/21 2021-04-01 12:00:00 2021-04-01 21:30:00
2         4/2/21 2021-04-02 12:30:00 2021-04-02 23:30:00
```

I was using `mutate(hours_fasted = difftime(start_fast_c,end_fast_c))`
Which will only calculate between the same line. Is there a way for me to calculate between line 2 and 1 so that I could do the time between 2021-04-01 21:30 and 2021-04-02 12:30?

Comment: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/lead-lag.html

Comment: Call `difftime` with just one column as an argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `difftime` as already suggested by camille:

In case your datetimes are not in `dttm` format you could use `ymd_hms` function from `lubridate` package

Using window function `lag` from  `dplyr` package gives you the possibility to calculate the difference from one row below.

adding `units` argument you could get the difference in minutes with `mins` or hours with `hours` etc...

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(across(ends_with("_c"), ymd_hms)) %>% 
    mutate(time_diff_min = difftime(end_fast_c, lag(start_fast_c), units = "mins"))
```

```
  dates_edited end_fast_c          start_fast_c        time_diff_min
  <chr>        <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>       
1 4/1/21       2021-04-01 12:00:00 2021-04-01 21:30:00  NA mins     
2 4/2/21       2021-04-02 12:30:00 2021-04-02 23:30:00 900 mins
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a sheet in a spreadsheet and populate it with formulas and data, then retrieve results programmatically if a sheet is not your preferred output.

In Google Sheets (and maybe others), you can label a calculated cell as 'duration' using the '123' dropdown menu.

I entered your four time values in A1, A2 and B1 B2, changing their display formats to make sure they were entered correctly.

Then in cell C1 I entered the formula B1-A2 and got **9:00:00**

Cell C1 can be formatted differently and\or used as the source of further formulas obviously.